# Histogram bars overlapping matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am able to build the histogram I need. However, the bars overlap over one another. 
As you can see I changed the width of the `bars to 0.2` but it still overlaps. What is the mistake I am doing?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from random import randrange

color = ['r', 'b', 'g','c','m','y','k','darkgreen', 'darkkhaki', 'darkmagenta', 'darkolivegreen', 'darkorange', 'darkorchid', 'darkred']
label = ['2','6','10','14','18','22','26','30','34','38','42','46']
file_names = ['a','b','c']
diff = [[randrange(10) for a in range(0, len(label))] for a in range(0, len(file_names))]
print diff
x = diff
name = file_names
y = zip(*x)
pos = np.arange(len(x))
width = 1. / (1 + len(x))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for idx, (serie, color,label) in enumerate(zip(y, color,label)):
        ax.bar(pos + idx * width, serie, width, color=color, label=label)
ax.set_xticks(pos + width)
plt.xlabel('foo')
plt.ylabel('bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(name)
ax.legend()
plt.savefig("final" + '.eps', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5,dpi=100,format="eps")
plt.clf()
```

Here is the graph: [image]

Comment: Sure. Give me 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the below example, you can easily get non-overlapping bars using a heavily simplified version of your plotting code. I'd suggest you to have a closer look at whether `x` and `y` really are what you expect them to be. (And that you try to simplify your code as much as possible when you are looking for an error in the code.)

Also have a look at the computation of the `width` of the bars. You appear to use the number of subjects for this, while it should be the number of bars per subject instead.

Have a look at this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subjects = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue')
# number of bars per subject
n = 5
# y-data per subject
y = np.random.rand(n, len(subjects))
# x-positions for the bars
x = np.arange(len(subjects))

# plot bars
width = 1./(1+n) # <-- n.b., use number of bars, not number of subjects

for i, yi in enumerate(y):
    plt.bar(x+i*width, yi, width)

# add labels
plt.xticks(x+n/2.*width, subjects)

plt.show()
```

This is the result image:

[image: barchart example]

For reference:

- http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html
- http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: I think the problem is the way in which I'm grouping.

Comment: @pistal: Then you should probably remove the plotting stuff from your question as it distracts potential readers from the real problem. Add input data and expected output to clarify and to enable us to reproduce the real problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `remove plotting stuff`? I did add some input data and the output has to be clear, that is, non-overlapping bars in the histogram.

Comment: @pistal: stop putting as much logic as possible into each line of code. Keep it simple, inspect your input data and see if it looks as expected when there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width of your bars is calculated from the three subjects, not the twelve bars per subject. That means you're placing multiple bars at each x-position. Try swapping in these lines where appropriate to fix that:

```
n = len(x[0])  # New variable with the right length to calculate bar width
width = 1. / (1 + n)
ax.set_xticks(pos + n/2. * width)
```